# How to accept user input command in batch file?

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, batch-file

I would like to write a batch file in which the user input would be run as a command, essentially functioning like command prompt.

Example:

```
batch file is run:
user input: echo hello
program output: hello
```

How would I implement this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26551/how-to-pass-command-line-parameters-to-a-batch-file

Answer (score 2):

Use `set /P` to get the user's input into a variable, then run the variable as if it's a command:

```
@echo off
set /P CommandVar=Command? 
%CommandVar%
```

From `set /?`:

> The /P switch allows you to set the value of a variable to a line of input entered by the user.  Displays the specified promptString before reading the line of input.  The promptString can be empty.

Comment: Oh wow, I never knew you could actually execute a command like that. Thanks. I learned something today. :)